# Django 2.2 model template boolean value change

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to create a very simple coupon system. You sign up for an email list, and are issued a database entry with the values for coupon identification, active status, and an email. I've been able to register them without issue, but I'm having trouble mentally figuring out how to redeem the coupon. I have a page/template setup to redeem the coupon, just can't figure out how to submit in order to change the status, as well as send back a query if it's been used already.

Also, sorry if I'm just missing something super obvious, I'm not feeling 100% today.

```
-- Template --

{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}

{% block content %}

<style type="text/css">
    input {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
</style>
<div style="background-color: purple; opacity: 0.7; margin: 10px;">
<br />
<p style="padding: 10px; font-size: 25px;">
  Enter id<br />

</p>
<form method='POST' style="margin: 20px;" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="color: black;" />
</form>
<br />
</div>
{% endblock content %}






-- urls.py --

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . views import coupon_view, coupon_redeem



app_name = 'coupons'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', coupon_view, name = 'main'),
    path('redeem/', coupon_redeem, name='redeem'),
]






-- Models.py --

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Coupon(models.Model):
    first = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    last = models.CharField(max_length = 80, default="")
    identification = models.IntegerField(unique = True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.last




-- Views.py --

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
from .models import Coupon
from .forms import CouponForm, CouponApplyForm
# Create your views here.

def coupon_view(request):
    form = CouponForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = CouponForm()
    context = {
        'form' : form
    }
    return render(request, 'coupons/coupon.html', context)

def coupon_redeem(request):
    form = CouponApplyForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        identification = form.cleaned_data['identification']
        try:
            coupon = Coupon.objects.get(identification__iexact=identification,
                                    active=True)
        except Coupon.DoesNotExist:
            request.session['coupon_id'] = None
    # Return to non-homepage, invalid code'
    context = {
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'coupons/redeem.html', context)
```

Results currently, Submit hit, no change in status.

Comment: No where in your `coupon_redeem` view are you updating/saving a Coupon instance

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for pointing that out. Though now I have a no save method for object. That I can sort out.